# hide scrollbar but able to scroll with mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to hide scrollbar to appear on a long div,but still able to scroll through mouse or keyboard arrow keys.I read another thread here about scrollable.Tried to use that..but could not implement that...could someone guide me how to implement that clearly or is there any other option with jquery or css?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on the browser compatibility of this, but you can have two div's - an outer div and a inner div. The inner div will have all your content. Your css could then look like this:

```
#outer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#inner {
    height: 200px;
    width: 225px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

That is, the inner block would be wide enough to contain a scrollbar, but have it hidden from sight by the containing div. This worked for me in webkit. You might have to fiddle with the widths to make sure text doesn't get cut off.

That said, I would carefully think about WHY you're trying to do this. This could be a huge usability issue for your users, as they will not have any indication that there is more content within the div.

Comment: Annoying workaround, but it does the trick. By using JS .scrollWidth you'd be able to define the width of the #outer div dynamically.

Comment: @chipcullen: Try your demo in Chrome/Safari: highlight/select a line and drag your mouse to the right and you'll see the scrollbar. Or use a textarea instead of the inner element and then fill it with some text. Then use the keyboard keys `Page Up` and `Page Down`.

Comment: @RainLover sure, you can see the scroll bar if you do that - my method here is definitely smoke and mirrors. I'm still not a fan of hiding a scroll bar at all.

Answer (score 1):

To do this is add the following css

```
.div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

This is saying that hey remove the display of the scroll bar but keep the functionality

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).