# Scrollable but no scroll bar

Tags: html, css

How can I let a DOM object such as div be able to scroll with scroll wheel on the mouse or by the arrow keys (like `overflow:scroll`), but not show the scroll bar (like `overflow:hidden`)?

Comment: I have no idea - gonna upvote it to compensate ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set bind an event listener to scrolldown / scrollup (via the mousewheel event, looking at event.wheelDelta to calc size and directino of scroll) and manually position an absoluteley positioned div inside another fixed height absolutely / relatively positioned div. So on scroll down you decrease the y position of the inner div, and on scroll up you increase the y position.

For arrow keys, just bind a similar function to keydown event checking for the down / up arrow as appropriate.

I made a jsfiddle exampling this technique here: http://jsfiddle.net/wsmithrill/U7ju8/32/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip javascript altogether, you can try what I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147701/hide-scrollbar-but-able-to-scroll-with-mouse/9153546#9153546).

Basically, have a container div that's slightly narrower than your content div. Have the container set to overflow:hidden, but the content div set to overflow:scroll. If the container is narrower, it will hide the scroll bar.

Comment: Glad you like it! Unfortunately, it's horrendous from a usability stand point - how is a user supposed to know there is more content out of site?

Comment: Your idea may be simple, but I have concerns about the idea to manually adjusting the width of the scroll bar, and just hiding something does not look clean.

Comment: It will be a problem, given that the scrollbars are OS dependent, so you'll need to take into consideration the *WIDEST* scrollbar you want to support. For example, most of linux's GTK themes bring their own scrollbars to firefox, so... use this wisely.

Answer (score 0):

if may need this to stop scroll down when you reach the top:

```
var top_val = $("#inner").css("top");
if (top_val.indexOf("-") > -1)
{
    $("#inner").css("top", parseInt($("#inner").css("top"), 10) + 5 + "px");  
}
```